# Add Org dynamically to Existing Hyperledger Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just setup a Hyperledger network. Then I followed [Add Org to channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html) document for adding new Org to the existing channel.This tutorial is manual work. Any way i can add new Org to existing channel dynamically. I need to add Org dynamically to my network. Please give any suggestion for doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you write a script to do your job?

Comment: Ok I understand. But I need to run the most of commands in bash terminal such as **docker exec -it cli bash**. Is possible to write a script  that run in separate bash terminal..???

Comment: it's not necessary to be in bash terminal to run commands. you can simply do:  docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=".....env variables.... cli peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l golang -p github.com/...path...

Comment: same goes for other commands , since you are following the tutorial you can see in the file eyfn.sh similar commands https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/eyfn.sh#L124

Comment: But I face some problems while run in direct terminal. Is any way are available to run script in bash terminal..?

Comment: I dont get you, what problems are you facing? if you are asking if you can run scripts in bash terminal...yes you can do that, simply create a .sh file and run from cli bash terminal

Comment: I need to run the command **docker exec -it cli bash** in an sh folder. Then I need to run the following command (in bash terminal) **peer channel create -o orderer0.Myname.com:7050 -c Mynamechannel -f /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/Myname.com/orderers/orderer0.Myname.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.Myname.com-cert.pem** . But after execute the first command, the terminal goes to bash and the second command is not working in my sh program

Comment: I am assuming your first command is docker exec -it cli bash and second command is peer channel create.... and you are running this from a sh file. if thats true then you dont need the first command just run 1 command:  **docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Org1.Myname.com/users/Admin@Org1.Myname.com/msp" cli peer channel create ....**

Comment: change the names of Org and domain accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it soon

Comment: Thanks @Harshit .It's working....